# Android: Add number to an existing contact with same number type

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to add a new number to an existing android contact programmatically with the same `Phone.TYPE`. But my code replaces the existing mobile number in the given `Phone.TYPE`(if any).

Eg. If a number `12345678` is stored under category `Mobile`, I can add another number `87654321` in the same category `Mobile` through `People`'s App. But, After running the below code, `87654321` replaces `12345678`. What's the way to store both numbers. The problem is that I don't know which `Phone.TYPE` is empty to store the new number in. That's why I'm using a default type. Below is my code.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

String where1 = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ? ";
String[] params1 = new String[] { oldNumber };
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(where1, params1)
       .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
       .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());

try
{
     cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
}
catch (RemoteException e)
{
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (OperationApplicationException e)
{
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is replaced as you are doing an update instead of a new insert. A new number should be a new insert operation as you have to create a new entry in the data table. For clarity you can prompt the user for the type of number or insert it with MOBILE type and let the user edit the contact later.

```
// Inserts the specified phone number and type as a Phone data row
op =
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)

        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, raw_contact_id)

        // Sets the data row's MIME type to Phone
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

        // Sets the phone number and type
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, phoneType);

// Builds the operation and adds it to the array of operations
ops.add(op.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getRawContactId(String contactId)
{
    String res = "";
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ contactId };
    Cursor c = ContentManager.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
        c.close();
    }

    return res;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
public static boolean addContactNumber(String contactId, String newNumber,@Nullable Object type)
{
    try
    {
        if (contactId == null || newNumber == null)
            return false;

        if(type == null)
            type = Phone.TYPE_WORK;

        ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        android.content.ContentProviderOperation.Builder t ;
        android.content.ContentProviderOperation b ;
        t = android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
        t = t.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawContactId(contactId));
        t = t.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        t = t.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber);
        t = t.withValue(Phone.TYPE, type);
        b = t.build();
        ops.add(b);

        ContentManager.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return false;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
public static boolean updateContactNumber(String contactId, String oldNumber, String newNumber,@Nullable Object type)
{
    try
    {
        if (contactId == null || oldNumber == null)
            return false;

        if(type == null)
            type = Phone.TYPE_WORK;

        String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
                + Phone.NUMBER + " = ? AND "
                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] numberParams = new String[]{contactId, oldNumber, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        android.content.ContentProviderOperation.Builder t ;
        android.content.ContentProviderOperation b ;
        t = android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI);
        t = t.withSelection(where, numberParams);
        t = t.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber);
        t = t.withValue(Phone.TYPE, type);
        b = t.build();
        ops.add(b);

        ContentManager.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return false;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
```

Sample :
    addContactNumber("313" , "+989139277303", null);

Adds +989139277303 number to contact

Comment: Please, explain your answer. Answers consisting of only of code dump are not really very helpful.